# fastapi prediction with machine learning model from mlflow works in local but not online on Heroku

Tags: heroku, fastapi, mlflow

When I test my API in local it is working fine:

[image]

When I test it online. It is still working fine.

[image]

When I make a prediction in local; it is still working fine. It uses a model saved online on MLflow to make the prediction.

[image]

But when I push my API online and try the same prediction, is it not working anymore.

When checking the status_code, I have an error 500:

[image]

And when trying to print the answer it says:

[image]

Any idea why?

Thank you

Comment: Were you able to catch the stacktrace from heroku logs?

Comment: not sure what the "stacktrace" is but when looking at heroku logs It seems the issue comes from my mlflow model not being found. mlflow.exceptions.MlflowException: Run '57dcb7c903b34XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX' not found

Comment: I was requesting the exception with it's call stack. So the problem is with the server side code. When you are loading the model from file you must be using a path which is valid in your local machine but fails in heroku deployment.

Answer (score -1):

The error 500 means the website does not exist. You need to build a docker image and push it online.

Comment: This error is something that is coming from application server. You could suggest website not available for gateway errors like 502 or not found 404.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).